# Using a variable to call a specific function in javascript instead of IF function

Tags: javascript, function

So I have a string that I want to draw onto a HTML5 Canvas using javascript. I have got *separate* functions that will draw each character of the alphabet.

I have used a for loop to iterate through the characters in the string.

```
let theText = "String"

for (let i = 0; i < theText.length; i++) {
  theText[i];
}
```

I also have functions for each character in the alphabet

```
function draw_A() {
  //code that draws A
}

... a through to x

function draw_X() {
  //code that draws X
}
```

Currently my solution to drawing the characters is

```
for (let i = 0; i < theText.length; i++) {
  c = theText[i];

  if (c == "A") {
    draw_A();
  }

  ... a through to x

  else if (c == "X") {
    draw_X();
  }
}
```

I know this method is inefficient and I have also tried using case, however, that is just a simplified version of what I'm doing already.

I know that if you want to insert a variable into a string in javascript you can use the ${} characters inside of `` to do this. The below code will insert the variable 'username' into a string.

```
let myString = `Hello ${username}, welcome to this script`;
```

Is there a similar way to do this with functions. I don't want to have to write 26 **if** or **case** statements to carry out something that I know should be much simplier

Comment: You should put your functions in an array (or object).

Comment: Why do you need separate functions for each letter? Is the code that prints each letter that complex? Could you not have one function that accepts a letter as an argument and then draws it?

Comment: @skyline3000 The code used to draw each letter is very complicated, the letter is not actually drawn with a drawText command, it is drawn bu individual rectangles and arcs. I have basically deigned my own type set for each letter and these need to be separate functions because of this

Comment: @SLaks I have already tried putting these into an array however, that is complicated and rather resource intensive. I was looking for something where I did not need a loop or lookup as this would be quite intensive

Comment: @CakeHook: Lookups are actually quite fast.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just create a lookup object:

```
const lookup = {
 a: draw_A,
 /*...*/
 x: draw_X
};
```

And then you can just do

```
lookup["a"]()
```

---

Currently you could do it a bit more hacky (/ugly) without a lookup object:

```
window["draw_" + "a"]()
```

Comment: Your answer was great until you proposed the horrible alternative at the end.

Comment: Hacky? Ugly? No, it's just the **wrong** thing to do.

Comment: Could I replace "a" with `${character}` so that it would run the correct function for a character in a string? Forgive me for not understanding, I am self taught :) but why is the last solution so bad? Also where does window come from in window["draw_" + "a"]() @Bergi @torazaburo @jonas-w

Comment: @CakeHook Sure you can do `const character = "a"; lookup[character]();`. The latter solution is so bad because it requires your variables to be global (which is bad)

Answer (score 1):

You can use an object literal that matches the character to the function

```html
let functionHash = {
  a : draw_A,
  b : draw_b
  //etc.....
}

functionHash['a'](); //Calls draw a
```

This will consume a fixed amount of memory. Another approach that doesn't use a data structure would be a switch statement. As long as the size of your incoming characters is constant.